# Selenium unittest - calling function from another file correctly in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-unittest

I have a function I want to use in my unittest:

```
class nos_admin_login():
    
        
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print('Mēģina ielogoties NOS kā admins')

    def fill_login(self):
        self.email = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email')
        self.psswrd = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
        self.nos_find_login_fields(self)
        self.nos_fill_login_fields(self)
        time.sleep(5)
    
    def nos_find_login_fields(self):
        print('Mēģina atrast login laukus')
        self.email = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email')
        self.psswrd = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
    
    def nos_fill_login_fields(self):
        print('Mēģina aizpildīt login laukus')
        self.email.send_keys(cred.nos_admin_email)
        self.psswrd.send_keys(cred.nos_admin_psswrd)
```

And I'm trying to run it in my testcase:

```
class NOSorders(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        print('setup') 
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.status = 'pass'

    def test_metodes_nosaukums(self):
        print('test test')
        self.open_page = nos.open_page_nos.open_page(self)
        self.nos_admin_login = nos.nos_admin_login(self)
        self.nos_admin_login.fill_login(self)
        time.sleep(15)
        
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

But I get:

```
nos_admin_login.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

At:

```
self.nos_admin_login = nos.nos_admin_login(self)
```

If I correct that portion to(removing the self from brackets):

```
        self.nos_admin_login = nos.nos_admin_login()
        self.nos_admin_login.fill_login()
```

I get two webdriver instances, which is not what I want.

I'm a bit confused by the usage of self in unittests and I did manage to run nearly identical testcase before, so I'm not sure what's wrong/different in this one?

I tried multiple thins, but then I get different error.

Also (but not the primary issue), I want to make

```
        self.email = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email')
        self.psswrd = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
```

Class variables, but I can not, because they need webdriver, but webdriver is only initialized in ***init*** function (so there is not multiple instances launched in the unittest).

Can someone school me a bit on this? Thanks!